# How to extract specific multiple values in JSON using python?

Tags: python, json, api, python-3.x

I Have to extract specific multiple values and print those specific values in a file if possible.

I tried the below code to do this

```
JSON value from URL is: 
{'data': [{'value': '0.0.0.0'}, {'value': '0.0.0.1'}, {'value': '0.0.0.2'}]}

import requests
import json
url = 'https://www.example.com'
response = requests.get('url', headers=headers , verify=False)  
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
value = json_data['data'][0]['value']
print (value)

output of this : 0.0.0.0
```

But i want to print in a file(.txt) all these values like below:

```
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.1
0.0.0.3
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: don't know how you expect it to say 3, that is not in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a loop

```
json_data = {'data': [{'value': '0.0.0.0'}, {'value': '0.0.0.1'}, {'value': '0.0.0.2'}]}

for x in json_data['data']:
  print (x['value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To write the values to a file, expand @ergonaut's answer as here:

```
json_data = {'data': [{'value': '0.0.0.0'}, {'value': '0.0.0.1'}, {'value': '0.0.0.2'}]}
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    for x in json_data['data']:
        f.write(x['value'] + '\n')
```

Test the entries in `test.txt`:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
for line in data:
    print line.rstrip('\n')
```

Output:
`0.0.0.0
0.0.0.1
0.0.0.2`