# How to get all of the "ids" within a python array

Tags: python, arrays, json

So I am pulling some json data using an API and it initially looks like this:

```
{
 "result": {
"elements": [
  {
    "id": "SV_3s0FmbrNancSmsB",
    "name": "Test Survey",
    "ownerId": "sdfsdfasdf",
    "lastModified": "2016-08-09T21:33:27Z",
    "isActive": false
  },
  {
    "id": "SV_dgJOVyJvwZR0593",
    "name": "Test Survey",
    "ownerId": "sdfdsfsdfs",
    "lastModified": "2016-08-04T17:53:37Z",
    "isActive": true
  }
],
"nextPage": null
  },
 "meta": {
 "httpStatus": "200 - OK"
}
}
```

So I want to pull all of the ids within this JSON using Python, and here is my code:

```
url = "random.com"

headers = {
'x-api-token': "dsfsdagdfa"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

data = json.loads(response.text)

id_0 = data['result']['elements'][0]['id']

print(id_0)
```

This will basically just print the first Id within the created array. What would I do to get all of the ids?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract specific multiple values in JSON using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308538/how-to-extract-specific-multiple-values-in-json-using-python)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this oneliner:

```
ids = [element['id'] for element in data['result']['elements']]
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work.  Im sure there is a more elegant way with map or list comprehension.

```
ids = []

for elem in data['result']['elements']:
  ids.append(elem['id'])
```

If you want to evaluate this lazily, make a generator comprehension!

`ids = (element['id'] for element in data['result']['elements'])`

Comment: Thank you! This works, but others are a bit cleaner!

Comment: Yes, they sure are!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
ids = [element['id'] for element in data['result']['elements']]
```